# Selecting characters in string numpy array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray of strings like that

```
HHMM = ['0000' '0001' '0002' '0003' '0004' '0005' '0006' '0007' '0008' '0009' ...]
```

Here the first two elements are the hour and the last two the minute. In order to convert to time format (using datetime), I want to separate this characters.

I tried doing

```
hour   = HHMM[::][0:2]
minute = HHMM[::][2:4]
```

but the result is this

```
print hour
['0000' '0001']

print minute
['0002' '0003']
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Do you want to end up with an array of `datetime64` values or just arrays of strings?

Comment: I want to split the two first and the two last characters (hours and minutes strings) in order to convert in a integer individuallly. Once this was made, I can make a map and convert them in datetime format. I only need to separate in individually arrays.

Comment: `HHMM.view('S2,S2')` might split it into a 2 field structured array.

Comment: Is this a list or real array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simple comprehension lists:

```
[u[:2] for u in HHMM]
#Out[39]: ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09']

[u[-2:] for u in HHMM]
#Out[40]: ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
for i in range(len(HHMM)):
    hour = HHMM[i][0:2]
    minute = HHMM[i][2:]
    print('Time: {}:{}'.format(hour, minute))
```

**Output:**

```
Time: 00:00
Time: 00:01
Time: 00:02
Time: 00:03
Time: 00:04
Time: 00:05
Time: 00:06
Time: 00:07
Time: 00:08
Time: 00:09
```

**EDIT:**

```
HHMM = ['0000', '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009']

hours = []
minutes = []

for i in range(len(HHMM)):
    hours.append(HHMM[i][0:2])
    minutes.append(HHMM[i][2:])

print('Hours: {}'.format(list(hours)))
print('Minutes: {}'.format(list(minutes)))
```

Comment: This only print the values, hour is not an array, still when I define `hour = [ ]`  before making the iteration. The same for minute. When print hour and minute, just print the last value.

Comment: @nandhos dude, here you go - is this what you wanted? Now hours and minutes are a type of collection

Comment: sorry, I missed append!

Comment: @nandhos no worries man, thank you for acknowladging my contribution ;D